# mat-select highlights previous value if clear a field

Tags: angular, angular-material

There is a mat-select element

```
<mat-form-field id="statusField">
     <mat-select disableOptionCentering placeholder="Status" formControlName="statusField">
         <mat-option *ngFor="let status of allTaskStatuses; trackBy: trackByFn" [value]="status">
               {{ status.name }}
         </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Also there is a button to clear the field

```
clearField(event: MouseEvent, fieldName: string): void {
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.filterFormGroup.get(fieldName).reset();
}
```

After I select any option and click the button to reset, the field becomes empty but in a dropdown the previous selection is still highlighted.

[image]

I've tried `.setValue(null)` instead of `.reset()` but there is no any difference.

If do the `console.log(this.fieldFormGroup.get('statusField'))` after the button is clicked, I see the `value: null` property.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this answers your questions, but why don't you simply set your selection to `''`?

I had a very quick try with a Stackblitz I found laying around: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-ox4sga?file=src/app/app.component.html). I added a 'clear' button and it removes the text and the previous selection... is this what you are looking for?